# 413 - request entity too large

Tags: magento-1.8, server-setup

When trying to save the config of PayPal module I get the following server error:

> 413 - request entity too large

which I think is very strange.

I have searched around and made changes to `lighttpd.conf`

Has any one else encountered this when making configuration changes?

Comment: This is most likely not a Magento issue but a problem of your server configuration. It can be caused on config pages when you have set a limit on the number of GET/POST variables to transfer to your server or a maximum size of the request in total. You will have more luck on http://serverfault.com or the lighttpd forum I think.

Comment: It's strange. The suggestion I get is to increase the amount of post data (which I have done). But its strange that saving config causes this error.